# Transfer a Response object to another process

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, cluster-computing

I am trying to pass an Express' `Response` object from child process `A` to child process `B`.

In `a.js`, I am doing the following `process.send(process.pid, res.socket);`

In `b.js`, I can get the response socket by using the following

```
process.on('message', (msg, handle) => {
    var output = { msg: msg, socket: handle };
    console.log(output);
    handle.on('end', () => console.log('disconnected'));
    handle.write('hello there client!');
}
```

When I print the contents of `output`, I do get the `msg: 4355` and `socket` is connected and contains the IP address and port of the connected client. But when I use the socket to write `hello there client!`, the client did not receive the response, and the server prints out `disconnected`. Please help?

My client is Postman.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `socket` is a TCP connection, so I just have to write HTTP response for my client to receive the message. It works now! :D